# Defining a function with multiple outputs that can't be organised into a matrix

Tags: matlab, function, output, containers, grouping

Is there any *natural* way to define a MATLAB function with multiple outputs that cannot or are inappropriate to "stack" into a matrix? For example, what if I want a function `f` that returns a `3x3` matrix `A` *and* a `4x4` matrix `B`?

I'm really surprised that this would even be an issue in MATLAB. Because in Python, all we need to do is `return A, B` which returns a tuple of the two. However it seems that MATLAB doesn't quite support the idea of containers. As a non-elegant workaround, I can use a `struct` to put the two pieces of data in, and the function goes something like:

```
function re = f(x)
%f: returns two dimensional-inconsistent matrices A and B
% function body as follows
....  
A = ...;
B = ...;

% put data into the struct 're'
re.A = A;
re.B = B;
end
```

Apart from possible performance issues, this approach looks very unnatural and clumsy. Is there any better approach?

Comment: i dont understand the problem, just define the outputs to be [A, B] surely?

Comment: @nkjt sorry I was thinking how to make it work like Python. Yes you're absolutely right. It's just that in matlab I'm gonna have make more effort if I only want to access the second output from a function, like in this case, `[~, second_out]=f(x);` whereas in Python I can just do `second_out = f(x)[1]`.

Comment: _Matlab doesn't quite support the idea of containers_ It does. The equivalent to Python's lists or tuples (containers of possibly heterogeneous things) is the [cell array](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MATLAB you can return any number of outputs with this syntax:

```
function [A,B] = f(x)
  A = ...;
  B = ...;
end
```

that is an even elegant solution than tuples used in python.
You can even control the behavior with the number of inputs and outputs (`nargin` and `nargout`) and discard outputs with a tilde. [More information here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).
I cannot think of a more elegant syntax.

Comment: Upvoted for _I cannot think of a more elegant syntax_ :-D

Answer (score 2):

Usually when having several outputs, one should declare the function as follows:

```
function [out1, out2, ... , outN] = funcName(in1,...,inM)
...
end
```

MATLAB also allows you to alter the behavior of your function based on the amount of requested inputs/outputs via the [`nargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html)/[`nargout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) functions, respectively (you can think of this as a form of overloading).

For example, you can specify as one of the inputs an array indicating which outputs you want the function to give, then populate the [`varargout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) cell array accordingly:

```
function varargout = funcName(in1,...,whichOut)
...
for indO = 1:numel(whichOut)
  switch whichOut{indO}
    case 'out1'
      varargout{indO} = out1;
    case 'out2' 
      ... etc
    case 'out6'
      varargout{indO} = out6;
  end
end
```

then call it using `[out6, out1] = funcName(inp, {'out6','out1'});`

See also [`varargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html).